# Save to File a Vector of Vector

Tags: android, file, object, vector, storage

i'm writing to you for a problem that i can't solve.
I have a Vector of Vector.

```
Vector<Vector<Item>> vectorItem;
```

I don't know how can i save it into a file, and after, how to load.

I try this:

```
public void save(String name, Context ctx, Vector<Vector<Item>> vectorItem) {
        try {
            String sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File dir = new File(sdCard + "/dir");
            File file = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath(), name);
            if(!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            FileOutputStream fos = ctx.openFileOutput(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(vectorItem);
            oos.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Vector<Vector<Item>> load(String name, Context ctx) {        
        Vector<Vector<Item>> vectorItem; = null;
        String sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File dir = new File(sdCard + "/dir");
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = ctx.openFileInput(name);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            vectorItem = (Vector<Vector<Item>>) ois.readObject();
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return vectorSezioni;
    }
```

But this is the error: 
12-29 16:57:07.140: W/System.err(32681): java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: 1st method: serialise it on saving and deserialise it on load; 2nd method: save 1st vector values on lines and second one with values separeted by a separation mark `,`,`;`.

Comment: Just nitpicking, but Vector is a legacy class.  If you must have synchronization, use Collections.synchronizedList, otherwise just use an ArrayList.  Also, refer to objects by their interface, not an implementation.  So use List<List<Item>>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you must guarantee you have WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission 'cause you're writing to the SD card.

Before the call to

```
File file = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath(), name);
```

you should call

```
dir.mkdirs();
```

to be sure the directory gets created.

Then, after you write the object to the output stream, you must flush it for all the data to get written before its closed

```
oos.flush();
```

Deserialization method should take into consideration the directory an the file name:

```
public Vector<Vector<Item>> load(String name, Context ctx) {        
    Vector<Vector<Item>> vectorItem; = null;
    String sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File dir = new File(sdCard + "/dir");
    File file = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath(), name);
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = ctx.openFileInput(file);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        vectorItem = (Vector<Vector<Item>>) ois.readObject();
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return vectorSezioni;
}
```

Hope it helps.